# AWS site not accessible from mobile

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I recently set up a new site on AWS EC2 instance.  It works fine from the office, but when I go to the site from my phone it hangs and then times out.  I'm new to AWS, so maybe I missed something during the setup.  It's a basic lamp stack.  Nothing in the logs.  I don't think requests are even getting to the server.  Any suggestions appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: can you paste your security group?

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: Turns out the site is not accessible anywhere outside my office... maybe that's why you're asking.  The public IP address is registered with the domain.  What else do I need to do?

Comment: In the security group do you have this rule set http://imgur.com/a/Xv8DJ

Comment: You guys (error2007s) are f* awesome.  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue from your question and comments is that you do not have http port 80 open to public. Please add below rule to your EC2 security group and your website will work everywhere.

[image]